# How can i align this slideshow div. I'm having trouble finding the rights css actions and or tags

Tags: html, css

How can i align this slideshow div. I'm having trouble finding the rights css actions and or tags. I'm making a website for my grandfather's carwash btw.

```
<div class="panel-grid" id="pg-24-4" ><div class="panel-grid-cell panel-                                      grid-cell-empty" id="pgc-24-4-0" ></div><div class="panel-grid-cell panel-grid-cell-mobile-last" id="pgc-24-4-1" ><div class="so-panel widget widget_sow-image panel-first-child panel-last-child" id="panel-24-4-1-0" data-index="4"><div class="so-widget-sow-image so-widget-sow-image-default-3f547a15eaaa">



</div></div></div><div class="panel-grid-cell panel-grid-cell-empty" id="pgc-24-4-2" ></div></div></div>        </div><img class="mySlides w3-animate-fading" src="https://scontent-atl3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/14900620_1873675446184555_4218607328795881506_n.png?oh=f57ce36acc7149a07a783e47f6c5ffd6&oe=5939F45B" style="width:75% ">
<img class="mySlides w3-animate-fading" src="https://scontent-atl3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/15578381_1899277530291013_6097098055128981675_n.png?oh=1d77dedac2e4d2a3aa3e742ddf8a7330&oe=592EA286" style="width:75%">

<img class="mySlides w3-animate-fading" src="https://scontent-atl3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/15109552_1882442211974545_8067326977000618969_n.png?oh=d8bd04a60a22732693cd949139a7a3b0&oe=593F9854" style="width:75%">

<img class="mySlides w3-animate-fading" src="https://scontent-atl3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/14947668_1875739499311483_4360663874853259721_n.png?oh=ed21e18ba001536c9975e9c26279fcff&oe=59280BA7" style="width:75%">
</div>
```

Comment: errr what slideshow ?

Comment: Please provide link to your website or a jsFiddle or at least a code snippet both from CSS and HTML. EDIT: We still need some CSS code. Maybe tell us the framework you are using or your grid system?

Comment: also, please read http://www.wikihow.com/Ask-a-Question-on-Stack-Overflow on how to ask questions properly. You need to provide a minimum example that someone can test

Comment: @AhmedMasud the myslides is a slide show. would u like the full code?

Comment: @NikosGatzoulis We **always** want code sample _within_ the question, and not to any external resources

Comment: @CadenSerrato We want a minimal working code sample reproducing the error, not a full webpage or code dump

Comment: @LGSon  Ive looked it over and this is the full slideshow code. I belive here is no error i am having trouble centering though. It is a silly problem.

Comment: @LGSon i appear to having some trouble editing the code at the top, should i reate anther question with the correct code and delete this?

Comment: Which ever work best for you

Comment: @LGSon Im making a new question

Comment: @LGSon https://github.com/CadenGS/as/blob/gh-pages/index.html